# How to add a new style in options of select depending the the condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't know JS at all, but I need some js features in my django project. I would be very grateful if you help me.
I would like to change the style for option tags of the tag select with id="id_car_model". It should to check the value attributes for each option tags and to match with the "pk", which it gets from JSON.

The condition: if value != pk add style="display:none". Each value should be matched with each pk. For this example the list should be with 1 and 2 pk.

And this select input should be inactive until it receives this JSON.

I have tried to find the solution, but I don't know to apply it.

html

```
<select name="car_model" id="id_car_model">
<options value selected>----------</option>
<options value="1">520</option>
<options value="2">720</option>
<options value="3">301</option>
<options value="4">308</option>
</select>
```

It gets JSON from django back-end.

main.js

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'car-model-ajax/',
        data: model_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            console.log(response.car_models)
            var jsonModels = response.car_models
            var models = JSON.parse(jsonModels)
            console.log(models)
            models.map(el => console.log(el.pk))
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        },
    })
```

It is in the console

```
{car_models: '[{"model": "adapp.carmodel", "pk": 1, "fields": {"…pk": 2, "fields": {"brand": 12, "model": "720"}}]'}
main.js:263 [{"model": "adapp.carmodel", "pk": 1, "fields": {"brand": 12, "model": "520"}}, {"model": "adapp.carmodel", "pk": 2, "fields": {"brand": 12, "model": "720"}}]
main.js:266 (2) [{…}, {…}]
main.js:267 1
main.js:267 2
```

Comment: There is two `pk` in the list (1, 2), so do you want to select first two options in the list by default?

Comment: I forgot to write the condition: if value != pk add style="display:none". Each value should be matched with each pk. For this example the list should be with 1 and 2 pk

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the task correctly - here the fixed version of your function (with comments in needed places):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'car-model-ajax/',
    data: model_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        // show all items (activate previously disabled)
        $("#id_car_model option:disabled").removeAttr('disabled');

        const models = JSON.parse(response.car_models).map((el) => el.pk);
        
        // hide all that we don't have in the models array
        $("#id_car_model option").each(function(val){
            if(!models.includes(val)){
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
})
```

Here's a code snippet you can play with:

```js
const idsToShow = [1,2];

$("#id_car_model option").each(function(val){
    if(!idsToShow.includes(val)){
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <select name="car_model" id="id_car_model">
  <option value="0" selected>----------</option>
  <option value="1">520</option>
  <option value="2">720</option>
  <option value="3">301</option>
  <option value="4">308</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work because models is - (2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {model: 'adapp.carmodel', pk: 1, fields: {…}}
1: {model: 'adapp.carmodel', pk: 2, fields: {…}}
length: 2

Comment: @Michaela yes, I've missed one thing, there should be:
const models = JSON.parse(response.car_models).map((el) => el.pk);

Fixed in original answer. Check it please.

Comment: @Michaela what the problem do you have? My answer is incorrect or what?